# How to draw this commutative diagram

Tags: pstricks, tikz-cd, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

[image: Draw lines to form triangle in latex]

Please, I want to draw the below diagram in latex and don't know how to go about it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE `xymatrix` is one of a good option, but post atleast the text, as no one wants to keyin ...

Comment: @MadyYuvi Hi :-) I am totally agree with you...For the user there is a documentation here https://www.jmilne.org/not/Mxymatrix.pdf or you can use tikz-cd package.

Answer (score 5):

I think a solution with `tikz-cd` has a more 'natural' feel. And once you have a diagram it can often easily be adapted to similar new ones.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
A  \arrow[rr,hook] \arrow[dr, "\varphi"'] & & M^+ \arrow[dl, "\varnothing"] \\
        & S  
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Quite likely it's `\phi` and not `\varnothing` (although I'm not sure one should use both `\varphi` and `\phi`). I removed the `\LARGE` instruction that might confuse the reader and, I guess, was just to make a bigger picture.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `tikz-cd` of course, but if you don't mean to learn this package and use it on a regular basis, I recommand to do it in plain Ti*k*Z, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) {$A$};
        \node[below right =of A] (S) {$S$};
        \node[above right =of S] (M) {$M^+$};
        
        \draw[right hook-latex] (A) -- (M);
        \draw[-latex] (A) -- (S) node [midway,left] {$\varphi$};
        \draw[-latex] (M) -- (S) node [midway,right] {$\varnothing$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: diagram with hooked arrow]

Comment: I disagree: the quality is definitely lower than the not-so-difficult `tikz-cd` form.

Comment: I agree that it can (and probably *should*) be drawn with `tikz-cd`. The only flaw I can see in my picture is the difference in length for both the diagonal arrows. But the diagram in `tiz-cd` has the same flaw (due to the math type of the node S).

Answer (score 1):

Just for comparison using `xy` package with the same tips of `tikz-cd` but with a not very good curved arrow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=2.2pc@C=1.5pc{
 A \,\ar[dr]_{\varphi} \ar@{^{(}->}[rr] & & M^{+}\ar[dl]^{\varnothing}\\
 & S &
 }
\end{document}
```

The code it is not very simple than `tikz-cd` but if I am able to do it, I think that one week you will be a very nice user to make commutative-diagrams.

PS: I will put `\emptyset` instead of `\varnothing`.

[image]